# Everyone watches the same embedded video

Tags: javascript, youtube, video-streaming, html5-video

I can embed videos with no challenge. I am trying to figure out how I can embed a video in a page, that was easy. I was wondering if I can make a webpage that loads the same instance for all users.

I am looking to do this with youtube embeds, preferrably in JavaScript. If its even possible. Here is the scenario

User 1 loads the page and the video starts at 0
User 2 loads the page while user 1 is already 2:32 in and the video starts at 2:32
User 3 loads the page while user 1 is still watching and the video starts at 2:32
ETC

Possible or not possible?

Comment: Have a look at meteor https://www.meteor.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible because the video is displayed on the client. You would have to send the current time of client one to the server, then resend it to user 2, but by the time client 2 gets the time it should start the display, user one will have watched a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be interested in multicasting - google it.  You won't be able to control the stream at the client, however.  It will just happen automatically because the clients will play the video as data is received.